# Создание панорамы 360* на лету

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создаю магазин на html, css, js, php.
Сейчас хочу реализовать просмотр панорамы 360* которая создается на лету. Для примера можно взять сайт с ювелирнемы изделиямы, тоесть сначала мы с списка выбираем камень который будет накладен на каблучку, а потом сам обруч, и в итоге у нас должна получится вот такая панорама с всех сторон:
[тык](https://www.jamesallen.com/engagement-rings/solitaire/14k-white-gold-15mm-comfort-fit-engagement-ring-item-22606)

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли такое? Тоесть создание панорамы с двух частей. Буду рад и другим идеям которые смогут помочь в решении сложившийся проблемы. Спасибо.

Comment: Она не создаётся на лету. Там тупо скачиваются заранее нарисованные jpeg-картинки

Comment: Это не панорама.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я делал такое с помощью jQuery-плагина [Interactive 3D](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/interactive_3d.html). Нужен набор фотографий, показывающий предмет с разных ракурсов (для плавности около 24 штук).

В вашем случае придётся создавать n*m наборов фотографий, где n - количество обручей, а m - количество камней.

Comment: я правильно вас понял, тоесть такую задачу все же можно решить? Очень важен тот факт что етот ефект просмотра должен быть создан с двух частей, на одном изображении нет сразу и камня и обруча, их нужно налаживать по отдельности

Comment: Я вроде объяснил. Не получится объединить. Вам нужно сделать 24*n*m фотографий.

Comment: Ппонял. спасибо

Comment: @Monach если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу, чтобы помочь сориентироваться пользователям, ищущим ответ на похожий вопрос